# Python - What's the use of if True:?

Tags: python

I just came accross the following code in an existent project, which I'm working on:

```
if True:
    x = 5
    y = 6
    return x+y
else:
    return 'Something
```

Inside the if True are lots of conditions and some will also return the function already.
Why would somebody write in that way? The code contained some other bugs also, but was just wondering about the if True: statement as it didn't make any sense to me. Probably also pretty stupid to ask it, but was wondering hehe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be a remnant of debugging or refactoring. It may be that instead of `True`, there was orginally a condition or variable there but it has now been replaced by `True`. The developer perhaps left it there without refactoring or cleaning it up all the way.

If you're free to edit the code as you wish and you're sure that the else is no longer needed, then you can remove it. It indeed makes no sense to have code in your codebase that will never run.

Answer (score 5):

`True` doesn't necessarily mean `True`

```
True = False
if not True :
    print "True is false" # This prints ok
```

Honestly, I don't think anyone would code like this.

Comment: Not quite related but I like the answer learned something new, I sure hope the previous dev didnt code in that way :O

Comment: plus 1 for making me laugh.

Comment: While this language quirk was definitely around for all of Python 2, it's been deprecated in favour of sane behaviour in Python 3 :)

Answer (score 1):

Does not make any sense to me, my *guess* is that someone wanted to have two distinct code paths that he could alternate between a'la using `#if 1 .. #else` -> `#if 0 ...` for debugging or such purposes.

Other possibility was that, as @SimeonVisser suggested, the original developer was refactoring  or cleaning up the code (and did not have an emulator that allows one to easily remove 1 step of indentation from a block of code)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a flag used for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply used to ensure that the `else:` block is never executed.
I have used `if True:` for some blocks to ensure that my code really does what I want. Usage for debugging or refactoring.
All in all it makes no real sense to use this in an application but for testing or debugging it's somehow acceptable.