# About if(true) { }

Tags: java

I'm not sure if I should ask about it ,but it just makes me curious (*I found it on my colleague's codes , but not exactly same ):

Under what circumtance that "`true`" bellow is accepted ? * Why this line is considered as **useless** that's what i'm asking  for explanation as I don't understand !! I meant  it means same like  `if (true==true)` , but why `if( )` always true for `default` circumtance?

```
public class UnknownChecking {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       if(true){
       System.out.println("something");
       }
    }
}
```

* It will print "something" .

Comment: When the bloodmoon aligns with Jupiter and frogs move to their African nesting areas.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense that code. true is always.... true. Maybe there was a previous condition that got lost leaving that useless statement.

Comment: If you are inquiring about any non-apocalyptic scenarios, you should clarify your question.

Comment: It's always true...and true is always true...it's a useless line

Comment: You might find this related ticket useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902350/python-whats-the-use-of-if-true

Comment: Read the following to understand about if() statement in java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: I have seen

    if (true)

used as a placeholder before but also always thought it was silly ive also seen 1 == 1 and other random stuff meant to remind them that, maybe? they should actually test for something but for now they just want it to pass.

Comment: I use it sometimes if I want to disable a block of code for testing purposes. Then I wrap that block around an if, and can toggle it in the code with false or true.

Comment: That's just like `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)`, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

true is always true. That is called [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology).

It's the same as writing `System.out.println("something");` without the `if` statement.